# “Delayed Write Failed” over the network

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, networking

I’ve got a program that runs over my local area network. All the users run it from a mapped drive letter. Lately the users have been getting “Delayed Write Failed” error messages. Microsoft has several articles on this but none of them have panned out. The software vendor claims it’s not their issue because when its run the machine acting as host for it, it runs great. So as long as no network is involved, all is well. Try to run it over the network and we get …
Windows was unable to save all the data for the file x. The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere.
The error itself would indicate a networking issue but all my other programs run fine over the network.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accepted answer [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650309/how-to-inhib-delayed-write-failed-message/682876#682876) which indicates there was a caching problem.
If all users mapping the drive face this problem, it is likely that the network is not working right.
Problems with the network include (1) bad network cards/drivers, (2) malfunctioning switches/connectors, (3) loops in the network causing data-loss by saturation.

There are some comments at this [EventID site page](http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=50&eventno=647&source=MRxSmb&phase=1);
it appears paid so don't expect most of the link going out from there to work.

You could also link the MS articles you have already covered for others;
will help to identify if they have another reference.

Comment: Thanks nik. I won't list the MS articles I've looked at because there are about 15 of them. But your Link to SO helped. You've also confirmed my belief that its networking related and that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

is the others users getting the same error ? check if the mapped driver has write permission enabled.